# sharepoint button to open major version of document

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I'm looking at a document approval process. Major versioning is enabled and I don't want to use minor versions. If someone edits a document a new version is created but its not approved.

Is it possible to have a button on the library that opens the last Major version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with OOTB Settings i.e. `Draft Item Security`, here you can set option `Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)`. It means that only user who do have permission to approve item and author will able to see unapproved version of document and all other user will see only approved documents.

You can configure it by following below steps

- Go to `Library Settings`
- Go to `Versioning Settings` and configure it as per below screen shot:

[image]

As per below screen shot currently document's version is 3.0 and it's not approved:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dont want to use 'Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)' because the Approver will require edit access. Giving Approver read access does not work. So possible solution is to leave draft security off (any user that can read) which displays all draft and published versions and have a button that users can press to see the last published version.

Comment: In that case, as per my understanding, there is no way to achieve your requirement using OOTB way or even using JSON formatting, you need to create [SPFx Field customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer). Let me know if you want to go with this approach then I can help you there